# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un buscador que envíe a cierta página dependiendo del producto encontrado?

Tags: php, mysql, buscador

Tengo un buscador que al hacer la búsqueda me muestra los resultados esperados, pero al hacer clic en cada producto me envía a la misma página (product.php), el problema es que cada producto (dependiendo de su categoría) tiene una página interior diferente (tengo tres páginas de producto diferentes, product.php, product-2.php y product-3.php) ¿Cómo puedo hacer que dependiendo del producto me envíe a la página correspondiente?

```
<?php require_once('conection.php'); ?>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['btnSearch'])){
    // Tomamos el valor ingresado
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['word']);

    // Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
    if (empty($search)){
        echo "Your search is invalid, try again...";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product like '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($result === false){
            echo mysqli_error($conn);
        }else{
            $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            // Imprimimos los resultados
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<p class='text-center'>Results for: <b>$search</b>";
                do {
                ?>

            <div class="col-sm-4 float-left">
            <figure class="product-index">
                <img src="images/products/<?php echo $row[productcode]?>.JPG" alt="<?php echo $row[product]?>" class="img-fluid rounded">
                <figcaption class="fig-product-index">
                <h6><strong><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row[id]?>"><?php echo $row[product]?></a>
                </strong></h6> <br> <p><strong><?php echo $row[state]?></strong></p> 
                </figcaption>
            </figure>                                       
            </div>

                <?php
                }
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
                echo "<p class='col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center'>Results found: $total</p>";
            }else{
                // En caso de no encontrar resultados
                echo "<p class='col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center'>No results were found for: $search </p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

¡Les agradezco por su ayuda! Saludos.

Comment: `<p><b><a href="productos.php?id=<?=$row['cve_imagenes'];?>"><?=$row['nombre'];?></a></b></p>` en esta linea es donde debes colocar en el atributo `href` de la etiqueta **`a`** la pagina hacia donde redirigir el producto. De alguna manera debes saber como validar para construir la url a donde va a redirigir

Comment: Exactamente como dice Cesar. Debes agregar  ya sea el Id del producto o un campo identificador  en el URL y luego en el la pagina que redirecciones coger el idenficador mentiandte GET

Comment: @CesarRomero, gracias! mira, tengo esto en la etiqueta **a** `<a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row[id]?>"><?php echo $row[product]?></a>`y funciona bien, me envía a esa página, pero lo que no se como hacer es que en vez de ir solo a "product.php" vaya a "product-2.php" o "product-3.php" dependiendo de la categoría del producto que aparezca en la búsqueda.

Comment: en la variable `$row` tienes la categoría? por ejemplo `$row['categoria']`

Comment: @CesarRomero si, ahí la tengo...

Comment: @CesarRomero no me funcionó poner el "if" entre do y while, lo que yo tengo entre medio es esto...

`<div class="col-sm-4 float-left"> <figure class="product-index"> <img src="images/products/<?php echo $row[productcode]?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row[product]?>" class="img-fluid rounded"> <figcaption class="fig-product-index"> <h6><strong><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row[id]?>"><?php echo $row[product]?></a> </strong></h6> <br> <p><strong><?php echo $row[state]?></strong></p> </figcaption> </figure> </div>`

Comment: Porque no te funciono el código? que error te da? Ese fragmento de código que colocaste en tu comentario, agrégalo a tu pregunta principal usando la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/262855/edit). También imprime la variable `$row` en tu pregunta y estas rutas existen `"product.php"  "product-2.php"  "product-3.php"`?

Comment: @CesarRomero disculpa la demora, ya actualicé el comentario y si, esas otras rutas existen, en el comentario lo expliqué mejor, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria una forma, validando si la `categoria == 1` irías a "product.php" en otro caso irías a "product-**X**.php" donde **X** seria la categoría.

```
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Imprimimos los resultados
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Resultados para: <b>$buscar</b>";
    do {
       ?>
          if ($row['categoria'] == 1) {
             <p><b><a href="productos.php?id=<?=$row['cve_imagenes'];?>"><?=$row['nombre'];?></a></b></p>
          } else {
             <p><b><a href="productos.php-<?=$row['categoria'];?>?id=<?=$row['cve_imagenes'];?>"><?=$row['nombre'];?></a></b></p>
          }
       <?php
    }while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    echo "<p>Resultados: $total</p>";
}else{
    // En caso de no encontrar resultados
    echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";
}
```